# how implement autocomplete nearby and location search google API works simultaneously

Tags: api, google-maps, autocomplete, keyword-search

Can I use the Google Maps autocomplete API to search by location and keyword (like restaurant/hotel etc) search simultaneously?

I want to implement the Google Maps search input box functionality:

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='YOUR_API'&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: Just a review comment: you have space `js?    key` here, this does not seems correct.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar: If only that was the only thing wrong about this question... I'm not familiar with the Google Maps API. What should that URL look like?